# Appending matrix A with matrix B

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, append

Say I have two matrices `A` and `B`. For example,

```
A = numpy.zeros((5,5))

B = np.eye(5)
```

Is there a way to append `A` and `B`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds to me like you're looking for `np.hstack`:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.zeros((5, 5))
>>> b = np.eye(5)
>>> np.hstack((a, b))
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.]])
```

`np.vstack` will work if you want to stack them downward:

```
>>> np.vstack((a, b))
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.]])
```

Comment: or `np.stack((A,B), axis=n)` for 0,1,2 to create a 3d array. :)   Two 5x5 array can be joined in at least 5 ways.